Not able to chain rag-prompt template with Langchain
I am trying to create a RAG based application for employee search, this is my notebook. In this code when i try to invoke the chain like this
base_model='deepset/roberta-base-squad2'

tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model)
model=AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(
    base_model,
    return_dict=True,
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map='auto',
    trust_remote_code=True
)

pipe=QuestionAnsweringPipeline(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
)

llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)

qa_chain = (
    {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | rag_prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

question='who is unis'
result=qa_chain.invoke(question)

I am getting this error

argument needs to be of type (SquadExample, dict)

I am stuck here, dont know how to proceed further and resolve this issue, any help would be appreciated
